# Store the values of radio buttons into ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to store the values of the radio buttons into the ajax call so that we can return some feedback based on the radio buttons selected, 1- Strongly Disagree and 5 - Strongly agree

I am unable to find a solution to match them with the radio buttons.
Can someone help please.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/u2ffm4at/4/)

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="provide-feed">
    <div class="survey-items survey-body survey-body-border modal-header">
        <div class="survey-rate">
            <p class="survey-q"></p>
            <form class="st-form">
                <p class="st-di"><strong>Strongly Disagree</strong></p>
                <p class="st-ag"><strong>Strongly Agree</strong></p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div survey-div-l">
            <p class="survey-q"></p>
            <form action="">
                <div class="col-md-1 rate-a"><strong>1</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 rate-b"><strong>2</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 rate-b"><strong>3</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 rate-b"><strong>4</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-1 rate-c"><strong>5</strong></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div">
            <p class="survey-q">question 1</p>
            <form action="">
                <label><input id="aone" type="radio" name="group1" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="atwo" type="radio" name="group1" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="athree" type="radio" name="group1" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="afour" type="radio" name="group1" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="afive" type="radio" name="group1" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div">
            <p class="survey-q">question 2</p>
            <form action="">
                <label><input id="bone" type="radio" name="group2" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="btwo" type="radio" name="group2" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="bthree" type="radio" name="group2" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="bfour" type="radio" name="group2" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="bfive" type="radio" name="group2" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div">
            <p class="survey-q">question 3</p>
            <form action="">
                <label><input id="cone" type="radio" name="group3" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="ctwo" type="radio" name="group3" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="cthree" type="radio" name="group3" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="cfour" type="radio" name="group3" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
                <label><input id="cfive" type="radio" name="group3" /><span class="radio-size"></span></label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div survey-body-border">
            <p class="">question 4</p>
            <textarea class="textinput text-area-width" placeholder=""></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="survey-div survey-body-border">
            <p class="">quesiton 5</p>
            <textarea class="textinput text-area-width" placeholder=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="survey-items modal-footer"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-feed" class="survey-submit view" /></div>

</form>
```

Also the values can be stored into variables like:

```
q1 = ans1
q2 = ans2
q3 = ans3
q4 = ans4
q5 = ans5
```

Comment: For starters, you need values for your radio buttons -- what value do you want to store based on the selected button?

Comment: Lets say if a user selects the first button - Strongly agree, and last button - Strongly disagree.
But in the backend we can store the values as - first button :1, second button :2, third button :3 and so on

Comment: Iam getting this error whenever a value is selected:

jquery.validate.min.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at jQuery.fn.init.delegate (jquery.validate.min.js:15)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.min.js:16)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a value attribute to your radio boxes

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"/>
...
```

Later when you're trying to retrieve the value you can just use .val() [jQuery]

```
$("input[name='group1']:checked").val();
```

> You should use the ID attribute only once per page.

If you want to store the value of a certain radio box in a variable use this code:

```
var q1 = $("input[name='group1']:checked").val();
```

### Q: How to store the whole form data in a variable?

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {

  var data = $( this ).serialize();

});
```

Comment: Since I have 5 questions, can you update the fiddle to be more precise. It will be a great help.

Comment: I'm here to help, Not write your code. If you have any unanswered question in my answer please say and Ill refine my answer.

Comment: I understand that @Yossi thanks again for your help.

Comment: How would you store the data to 
var data = $("#provide-feed").serialize();

Comment: Updated the original answer.

Comment: this is the correct solution but its not storing the value of the radio button selected, instead it is giving the answer as ON. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
$("#submit-feed").submit(function(){
  var q1  = $("#group1") .val();
  var q2  = $("#group2") .val();
  var q3  = $("#group3") .val();
  var q4  = $("#group4") .val();
  var q5  = $("#group5") .val();
  var s = {
  "q1  ":q1,
  "q2": q2,
  "q3": q3,
  "q4": q4,
  "q5": q5
 }

 $.ajax({
    url:'check.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:s,
    success:function(data){
    $(".survey-div") .html(data);
  }
   });
 return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Balaji I used some of your help as well. But can you store the values of each radio button since now its giving me the answer as, q1: on, q2: on and so on, where as I want to store them as q1: 1, q2: 3 based on the radio buttons selected.

Comment: @Nancy Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be using all those forms inside forms for one.

Also the submit button isn't running your javascript within your fiddle, it is just submitting the form. If you want it to submit via the ajax in the javascript, make it a type='button' and add in something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-feed").click(function(){
       provideFeedback();
    });
});
```

The line where you are serializing the form I believe will work. And as mentioned, you'll need values for the radio buttons.